# Can I mock the bpy module in a unit test?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I'd like to write unit tests for my addon. I do professional development in C# and I'm used to using the Moq package for mocking classes and functions. Is there a similar library in Python? I'd like to mock the `bpy` so that I can verify that the correct `bpy` functions were called with the correct parameters.
For example, something that looks or feels like this:

```
# (this is not real python code)
def Test_Create_And_Rename_Object():
    # arrange
    mockBpy = mock<bpy>()
    mockBpy.Setup(b => b.ops.someFunction())
    testObject = TestClass(mockBpy.object)

    # act
    renamedObject = testObject.createAndRename("new name")

    # assert
    mockBpy.Verify(b => b.ops.someFunction(), Times.Once)
    Assert.AreEqual("new name", renamedObject.Name)
```

(Sorry if this feels like C#. I've never written unit tests in Python before)

Is this possible? Specifically, can I mock the `bpy` module?

Comment: I don't think you can mock `bpy` without a Blender instance is running. But maybe I'm wron

Comment: @Hikariztw What if I created a wrapper around bpy that simply passed arguments through? It would look and feel exactly like bpy. Could I mock the wrapper class?